# Does the absolute values of the %IncMSE in Random Forest hint at predictive power of a variable?

Tags: modeling, random-forest, biostatistics, importance

I am new to machine learning. I am researching the drivers of plant species richness in woodlands. I have the species richness and a set of predictors, eg, pH, soil organic matter etc for around 100 woods. I have used the %IncMSE from a random forest model to rank my predictors and hence discuss which predictors are more important in my data set .

My question is this -  does the absolute value of the %IncMSE tell me something? My richness varies from 20 to 150 across my 100 woods, and my maximum %IncMSE is around 10, (taking into account that it fluctuates a bit on repeated runs of the model). It seems to me that this variable is not having a huge effect anyway. Would you expect to see a larger change in the %IncMSE for a model in which the variables were explaining a lot?